# Use a2dp profile to have headphones be used as input

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones, debian, bluez

I was wondering if it's possible to use my headphones+microphone just as a microphone using a2dp profile.

I have problems using HSP because the quality of sound is very poor so i was thinking of using 2 Bluetooth headsets, one as real earphones and one as a mic.

I know that ad2p is unidirectional but can I choose if use it as input (microphone) or output (earphone)?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Either one or another.

Comment: one or another it means that I can use mic or earphones?

Comment: It means A2DP (Stereo, no microphone) or HFP (mono + microphone).

Comment: so a2dp is just for sound in output. Ok thanks very much